# how to make an instance of a subclass of type base class C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, subclass, abstract, superclass

I've created an abstract class called Vehicle and have 2 sub classes: Motorcycle and Automobile.
How can I create an instance of Motorcycle by using type Vehicle?
So something like this:

```
Vehicle m=new Motorcycle();
```

I am able to access all properties of the Vehicle class but it is not seeing the properties of the Motorcycle class.
Thanks

Comment: Well, either don't declare it as `Vehicle` but as `Motorcycle` or cast it to `Motorcycle` where you need to access properties or methods from this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an instance of `Motorcycle` is *seen as* as `Vehicle`, then it, quite naturally, cannot give you access to `Motorcycle`'s unique properties. That's the point of inheritance.

To access them, you have to [type-cast the instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx):

```
Vehicle v = new Motorcycle();
((Motorcycle)v).MotorbikeEngineVolume = 250;
```

When you cannot be sure the instance truly is a `Motorcycle`, use the [`is` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx):

```
Vehile v = …
…
if (v is Motorcycle) 
{
    ((Motorcycle)v).MotorbikeEngineVolume = 250;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By writing above statement you will be able to access only those members of Motorcycle which are either inherited from Vehicle or overridden in Motorcycle but if you want to  access those  members of Motorcycle which are not part of Vehicle then you have to write:
Motorcycle m=new Motorcycle();
By using this instance you will  be able to access members of derived class .
Thank You!